# Converting a XML to Generic List of interface type objects

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a generic collection and I need to fill in objects stated in XML doc, however the problem is that object type is IProduct (which is interface).

```
public static List<IProduct> prod = new List<IProduct>();
```

XML file to read from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<Products>
-<Product Name="Buttermilk">
<Price>135</Price>
<Quantity>5</Quantity>
</Product>
-<Product Name="Cooked sausages">
<Price>135</Price>
<Quantity>5</Quantity>
</Product>
-<Product Name="Red meat">
<Price>12</Price>
<Quantity>5</Quantity>
</Product>
-<Product Name="Shubat">
<Price>12</Price>
<Quantity>5</Quantity>
</Product>
```

Please advice to me, how to fill in the list using LINQ.

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see any of your attempts in your question

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get far:
prod = (
                from p in XDocument.Load(XMLloc).Root.Elements("Products")
                select new

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. It looks as though that you need to serialise the XML into a class that inherits `IProduct`. You could use LINQ, but I think serialising is probably better here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use the XmlSerializer:

```
           XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyClass>));

           using(FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite("filename"))
          {
                 List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
                 serializer.Serialize(stream, list);
           }

           using(FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("filename"))
           {
                  List<MyClass> dezerializedList = (List<MyClass>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            }
```